# Interesting modulo operation result

Tags: math, actionscript, floating-point, precision, modulo

On my Windows desktop I multiply two numbers:

```
var a:Number = 31.05263157894737;
trace(a * 19) // will print '590'
```

It's obvious that dividing 590 by `a` leaves a remainder of 0, right? Well for some reason I get a differend result:

```
trace(590 % a) // will print '31.05263'
```

My question is **How does this happen? Why does 1 % 0.5 give a correct remainder of 0?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`31.05263157894737 * 19` is not exactly `590`, it's `590.00000000000003`

In other words, `590.00000000000003 % 31.05263157894737 = 0`, but since `590` is slightly smaller, it will be just slightly less than required to reach/wrap around to 0.

Either way, even if you used what would in source code look as exact numbers will seldom give you exact results in floating point math, since not all numbers can be represented exactly by single/double types, and even tiny rounding errors can (as in this case) give fairly non obvious results.

Comment: Is action script using decimal floating point internally? Otherwise we could add that 31.05263157894737 (the double) is probably not 31.05263157894737 (the decimal fraction)

Comment: Yep, [`The Number data type adheres to the double-precision IEEE-754 standard.`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html).

Comment: "`31.05263157894737 * 19` is not exactly `590`" Well, it is when computed as IEEE-754 double precision numbers. It looks like it was computed using extended precision - or the literal was erroneously converted to `31.052631578947373469645754084922373294830322265625` instead of `31.052631578947369916932075284421443939208984375`. (It may be that Action Script deviates from ECMA Script here and allows that to happen, ECMA demands conversion to the nearest value.)

Comment: @DanielFischer isn't libm fmod behind the % operator? If that's the case, and if fmod is correctly implemented, it acts as if performing the exact quotient and remainder, then round the result to nearest floating point value.